How can I get non-stale data from lights when running a python script in blender with the '--background' switch?
I have a python script that changes between frames and then prints out the light power value.
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1)
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
print(bpy.data.objects.get("test_light").data.energy)

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(3)
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
print(bpy.data.objects.get("test_light").data.energy)


The output is the same for both print statements (i.e data is stale for the subsequent call), even though the power values are different between the frames. The research I have done suggests that the data can become stale, but that bpy.context.view_layer.update() should force the data to be updated. This works if I run the script normally in blender, but the problem re-occurs if I use the --background switch. Is there any workaround for this?

I tested this in Blender 4.2 using .\blender.exe --background C:\test\test.blend --python C:\test\s.py. I added keyframe at frame 1 with Power value 1000 then another keyframe at 3 with Power 2000. And when I run your script it works. Maybe you are missing a keyframe at 1 or maybe keyframe 2 is changing the value back to the same as keyframe 1? Can you show a screenshot of the Power value at frame 1, 2, and 3? Or share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com. What command are you running?

Your script works fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/FBiut6v

It may be a Blender 4.1 issue? I'll try upgrading my blender and report back.

I tried with version 3.6, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2. All work fine. Are you using the similar structured command as me? .\blender.exe --background C:\test\test.blend --python C:\test\s.py

I'm not sure how you're running the script, but it works for me on Blender 4.2. Be sure to use the correct syntax when running the script. For example:
.\blender.exe --background C:\test\test.blend --python C:\test\test.py


